# SASS, Rails 3.1: Loading stylesheets in vendor/assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, sprockets

I'm using SASS to load stylesheets in a Rails 3.1(sass-rails 3.1) app. For example, sass partials in `app/assets/stylesheets` are loaded using `@import` in `application.sass` -

```
 @import "pages/common"
 @import "pages/**/*"
 @import "jquery-ui.css"
```

Now, I also want to load `vendor/assets/stylesheets`. Note that I'm not using `require vendor`, as `@import pages/*` seems to be the sass recommended way of doing it. Files here will be `css`, and not `sass` or `scss`.  I cannot use `@import ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/*` as it works only for `sass` and `scss` files.

Is there any way of doing this ?

**Update**

What I have now is this.

`application.css.scss`

```
//= require_tree .
//= require vendor
//= require_self
```

This includes all the sass partials mentioned above. The `require vendor` in

`vendor/assets/stylesheets/vendor.css` looks like

```
//= require_tree .
```

A caveat of this approach is that sass mixins(user defined & plugins) and common variables are not available in all partials. What I have now is a `_common_imports.sass` which I `@import` first thing in all partials.

`common_imports.sass`

```
@import "colors"
@import "compass/css3/gradient"
@import "compass/css3/border-radius"
@import "compass/css3/box-shadow"
```

Importing `common_imports` in all partials feels very repetitive.

Comment: Question: Where did you find documentation on using the /**/* pattern to @import a directory? It seems to work, but I can't find it referenced anywhere.

Comment: @robertwbradford: it is a monkey patch to sass in Rails 3.1+

Comment: can't you mix sprockets & sass directives? so have a `require vendor` in `application.css.scss` and an `@import "pages/**/*"` but no `require_tree .` ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, I think this might help.

Add the following to `config/application.rb`, inside the `class Application < Rails::Application` block:

```
config.sass.load_paths << File.expand_path('../../lib/assets/stylesheets/')
config.sass.load_paths << File.expand_path('../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/')
```

I've just added the above to an app, and the following directives are now both working:

- Import Sass:
  `@import 'grid'` in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss` finds the file `vendor/assets/stylesheets/_grid.scss`;
- Import regular CSS:
  `@import 'background'`, again in `application.css.scss`, finds `vendor/assets/stylesheets/background.css`.

Does that help? Sorry if I've misunderstood the problem!

Comment: the ```config.sass.load_path``` bit is not required anymore.

Comment: Interesting, is that because of updates in Compass or Rails 3.1.1?

Comment: I really don't want to have to import each file in `vendor/assets/stylesheets` separately. Is there a way to, in addition to using `@import blah`, also use `= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets`? I can't get them both to work together.

Comment: Hi @chadoh, I think unfortunately this may be considered undesirable, for reasons better explained [here](http://groups.google.com/group/sass-lang/browse_thread/thread/8edae9d1f738064f?pli=1). If the import order really is irrelevant to you, perhaps a simple shell script to generate some kind of 'imports' file would be best, and then you can simply `@include` that file.

Comment: Correct answer.  Only cleanup I would suggest is something more like `config.sass.load_paths += %w(vendor lib).map {|l| Rails.root.join(l, 'assets', 'stylesheets') }` to get around the relative paths and slightly DRYer.  _Eventhough this doesn't fully answer the original question with regards to whole directory inclusion_.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you'll need to restart rails if you created any new vendor/* directories (e.g. vendor/stylesheets). If you're seeing this in Rails 3.2 or later, this is probably the most likely culprit.

Answer (score 3):

> Try changing the extension to `.scss` for your vendor stylesheet.

Once I did this, SASS was able to find the required import.

Answer (score 3):

You can use bellow path in order to load assets files from vendor/assets.

Put below line into your application.css file, that will work great.

```
 *= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/.
```

same thing can be done for Javascript assets.

Comment: It's not pretty but this is definitely the best and simplest answer for including all stylesheets in vendor/assets/stylesheets in a Sprockets manifest. I don't think you need the trailing /. though.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

Hum, I'd say you're using the asset manager in a strange way.

Everything in app/assets/*, lib/assets/* and vendor/assets/* are mapped at the same place in /assets/ so, on the web side, it seems like they're all in the same folder.

What you should do, as you're in rails 3.1 is not use css/sass `@import` but sprockets `require`.

You should have at the top of your application.sass :

```
// require pages/common
// require_tree ./pages
// require jquery-ui
// require_self
```

so that sprockets put everything in the same file in production and you don't have to load a bunch of files.

Comment: Problem with using sprockets here is that variables are not shared across partials. For example, colors variables defined in ```pages/common``` will not be visible in ```pages/home```. Instead now, each partial has to ```@import``` the common required bits.

Comment: Ah, yes, I don't think it was supposed to be used that way, yes. I don't quite know how to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using engines, this get more tricky. A quick monkey path is to include the engines vendor path in the `SASS_PATH` Environment-variable. This is what worked for me in the `engine.rb`:

`ENV['SASS_PATH'] = "#{ENV['SASS_PATH']}:#{File.expand_path('../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/')}"`

From that point on, you could always put this into a method to DRY it up when you're including multiple engines in your project.