# Bower and Rails Asset Pipeline Import

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, bower

I have used Bower to install a selection of components into my Rails app.

The components are in `/app/vendor/assets/components`

I have installed the hidpi scss file and that lives at:

```
/app/vendor/assets/components/sass-hidpi/_hidpi.scss
```

Now, I need to get that scss file imported into my main application.css.sass file which lives in `/app/assets/stylesheets`

I have tried:

```
@import url(<%= asset_path '_hidpi.scss' %>)
```

by adding .erb onto the end of my application.css.sass file but that just outputs:

`@import "/assets/_hidpi.scss"` in my compiled stylesheet which obviously is wrong.

How can I get the file imported and compiled without moving it from the components directory that bower installs to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding the following to `config/application.rb`, inside the `class Application < Rails::Application` block:

```
config.sass.load_paths << File.expand_path('../../vendor/assets/components/')
```

from [SASS, Rails 3.1: Loading stylesheets in vendor/assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373751/sass-rails-3-1-loading-stylesheets-in-vendor-assets)

Comment: Thanks. I already had config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "components") set in application.rb but that made no difference. The line you posted gave the following error too: environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: I changed the answer to include the `.configure do` part. You add it before the `.initialize!` line.

Comment: Ok, so that allows my app to run but the mixin still cannot be located. It seems like Sass is not looking in the right locations for the file: Sass::SyntaxError at /
File to import not found or unreadable: hidpi.scss.
Load paths:
  Sass::Rails::Importer(/Users/neil/code/neil.co.uk/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass.erb)
  /Users/neil/code/neil.co.uk/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/neil/code/neil.co.uk/vendor/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets

Comment: I guess it only works if you want to include it using the asset pipeline. Changed it again. Sorry.

Comment: This worked perfectly! config.sass.load_paths << File.expand_path('vendor/assets/components/')   Thankyou so much. Highly appreciated